# How to create new vm using existing VHD image in blob storage in azure cli 2.0?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli2

We have a custom vhd image in our blob storage and we want to create a new vm using that vhd image through cli 2.0 in azure. Can anyone point me right direction to do so or any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use this script to create Azure VM, like this:

```
az vm create -n MyVm -g jasonvm2 --use-unmanaged-disk --os-type linux --public-ip-address "" --attach-os-disk https://jasonvm2disks653.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/jasonvm220170915094051.vhd
```

We can use `--attach-os-disk` to specify the VHD's URL:

```
--attach-os-disk
```

> Attach an existing OS disk to the VM. Can use the name or ID of a
>   managed disk or the URI to an unmanaged disk VHD.

More information about `az vm create`, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az_vm_create).

Comment: Hello Jason, but when we use this how can we pass the login credentials which are not applicable. my script az vm create -n CentosBaseVM -g MyRG --use-unmanaged-disk --os-type linux --public-ip-address "" --attach-os-disk https://link.blob.core.windows.net/imagevhds/CentOS7_3_base.vhd --admin-username uname --admin-password pwd --subnet subnet --public-ip-address "" --nsg "" --size Standard_DS1_v2

Comment: @Arun Please use `--ssh-key-value`, the SSH public key or public key file path.